# Embedding Python with NumPy & SciPy in a macOS app

Tags: xcode, macos, python-embedding

Is there a more streamlined process in embedding a Python interpreter, with numpy and scipy libraries, in a macOS application project using XCode? I suppose, to be more specific here, embedding Python, with numpy and scipy libraries, that does not link to any dylibs that are licensed with GPL?

Reason why I ask is that I have noticed that the contents of numpy & scipy's folders in my Python source installation both contain a dylibs folder:

[image: dylibs]

In addition, both libraries indicated in their respective License.txt file that:

> This binary distribution of NumPy also bundles the following software:
>
> Name: 
>   GCC runtime library Files: .dylibs/*
>   Description: dynamically linked to files compiled with gcc
>   Availability: https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/
>   License: GPLv3 + runtime exception
>
> This binary distribution of Scipy also bundles the following software:
>
> Name: GCC runtime library
>   Files: .dylibs/*
>   Description: dynamically linked to files compiled with gcc
>   Availability: https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/
>   License: GPLv3 + runtime exception

While I understand that numpy and scipy are licensed under BSD, the way I am using these libraries entails I have to embed the Python interpreter in my application's bundle. So, I am a bit of a loss, or perhaps I am simply misunderstanding what it means to embed Python in an application. Can anyone shed light on this particular situation?

For additional reference, these are the instructions I have followed for embedding Python in a Cocoa application:

[How to embed python in an Objective-C OS X application for plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660287/how-to-embed-python-in-an-objective-c-os-x-application-for-plugins)

[Getting Python to work in Cocoa App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624324/getting-python-to-work-in-cocoa-app)

Any input is appreciated. Thank you.